# Single row repeating instead of displaying

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pretty new at PHP/MySQL, so please be patient with me.

I am trying to get a list of members in a table to show up on a page. Right now it's showing the first member about 10 times and not displaying anyone else's name. I DID have it working, but I don't know what happened. I just want it to display everyone's name once. Here is my code:

```
<?php $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `member_staff` WHERE `username`='$_SESSION[USR_LOGIN]' AND `status`='Active'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($select);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($select);
$teaching = $row[teaching];
if ($rows==0){echo "Sorry, you don't appear to be a professor.";}
else { ?>

<?php }
    $select2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `classes_enrolled` WHERE `course`='" . $teaching . "' ORDER BY `student_name`") or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($select2);
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($select2);
    $student=$row2[student_name];
    if($count==NULL) {
        echo "<table width=\"80%\">\n";
        echo "<tr><td><center>Nobody has registered for your class yet!</center></td></tr>\n";
        echo "</table>\n";
        echo "<br /><br />\n\n";
    }

    else {
        echo "<center><font size=\"3\"><b>YEAR 1, TERM 2</b></font></center>";
        echo "<table width=\"80%\" class=\"table-stripes\">\n";
        echo "<tr><td width=\"50%\"><b>STUDENT</b></td></tr>\n";
    $select3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username`='" . $student . "'") or die(mysql_error());
    $row3 = mysql_fetch_array($select3);
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($select2)) {
        $house=$row3[house];
        echo "<tr><td><strong class=\"$house\">$student</strong></td></tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>"; }
?>
```

Comment: Which query is the one repeating? 1,2 or 3?

Comment: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: And please don't use obsolete HTML elements like `<center>` and format your page using tables unless a table is really required.

Comment: e.g. replace `<center><font size=\"3\"><b>YEAR 1, TERM 2</b></font></center>` with `<h2>Year 1, Term 2</h2>`

Comment: Personally I would start over, but your current problem is probably that you never update your `$student` variable. You should update that in the last loop as well.

Comment: @Lock It is select2 that is repeating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I miss look on your code, since it is mess, but disregard the mysqli and mysql thing, you want to show how many student in the teacher's classes.

```
<?php $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `member_staff` WHERE `username`='$_SESSION[USR_LOGIN]' AND `status`='Active'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($select);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($select);
$teaching = $row[teaching];  <--- This only get first row of the course, if you want multiple course under same username, you need to loop it.
if ($rows==0){echo "Sorry, you don't appear to be a professor.";}
else { ?>

<?php }
    $select2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `classes_enrolled` WHERE `course`='" . $teaching . "' ORDER BY `student_name`") or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($select2);
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($select2);
    $student=$row2[student_name];  <----- This only get the first row of the student name, if you want multiple student under a course, you need to loop it.
    if($count==NULL) {
        echo "<table width=\"80%\">\n";
        echo "<tr><td><center>Nobody has registered for your class yet!</center></td></tr>\n";
        echo "</table>\n";
        echo "<br /><br />\n\n";
    }

    else {
        echo "<center><font size=\"3\"><b>YEAR 1, TERM 2</b></font></center>";
        echo "<table width=\"80%\" class=\"table-stripes\">\n";
        echo "<tr><td width=\"50%\"><b>STUDENT</b></td></tr>\n";
    $select3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username`='" . $student . "'") or die(mysql_error());
    $row3 = mysql_fetch_array($select3);
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($select2)) {
        $house=$row3[house];  <----This only show the first row of $house under same student, so you need to loop it too.
        echo "<tr><td><strong class=\"$house\">$student</strong></td></tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>"; }
?>
```

So what you really want to do is

```
<?php 
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `member_staff` WHERE `username`='$_SESSION[USR_LOGIN]' AND `status`='Active'");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($select);
if ($rows==0){echo "Sorry, you don't appear to be a professor.";}
else { ?>

<?php }
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $select ) ) {
      $teaching = $row[teaching];
      $select2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `classes_enrolled` WHERE `course`='" . $teaching . "' ORDER BY `student_name`") or die(mysql_error());
      $count = mysql_num_rows($select2);
      if($count==NULL) {
        echo "<table width=\"80%\">\n";
        echo "<tr><td><center>Nobody has registered for your class yet!</center></td></tr>\n";
        echo "</table>\n";
        echo "<br /><br />\n\n";
      } else {

        while( $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($select2) ) {
           $student=$row2[student_name]; 
           echo "<center><font size=\"3\"><b>YEAR 1, TERM 2</b></font></center>";
           echo "<table width=\"80%\" class=\"table-stripes\">\n";
           echo "<tr><td width=\"50%\"><b>STUDENT</b></td></tr>\n";
           $select3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username`='" . $student . "'") or die(mysql_error());
           while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($select3)) {
              $house=$row3[house];
              echo "<tr><td><strong class=\"$house\">$student</strong></td></tr>";
           }
           echo "</table>"; 
        }
    }  // END ELSE
 }
} // END ELSE
?>
```

Comment: This didn't work. It's still displaying one name a dozen times. :/

I will make the changes suggested and also do some reading. I thought this would be a simple fix.

Comment: The problem could also be with ``$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `member_staff` WHERE `username`='$_SESSION[USR_LOGIN]' AND `status`='Active'");``. It should be ``$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `member_staff` WHERE `username`='".$_SESSION[USR_LOGIN]."' AND `status`='Active'");``

Comment: This worked perfectly! I'm going to compare my code to yours to really see what I did wrong. Thank you so much for your help!